# ID25/rails_emoji_picker gem not giving support for staging and develop environments

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

https://github.com/ID25/rails_emoji_picker/blob/master/lib/helper/emoji_helper.rb

Line # 62, Method: def insert_image_to_image_tag(string, img)

I just want to override this function in order to add support for multiple environments. As for my case i need to add staging environment support.

```
def insert_image_to_image_tag(string, img)
  return stanadrt_replace(string, img) unless defined? Rails

  if Rails.env.development?
    stanadrt_replace(string, img)
  elsif Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
    url = image_tag("emoji/#{img[:name]}.png")[/img.*?src="(.*?)"/i, 1]
    string.gsub!(img[:char], url)
  end
end
```